# how to use cmd multiple time when using it with node.js or karma or anythng else on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd, karma-runner

For example - I could run some node.js script from commandline, like `node server.js` but after that cmd block input and if you want to do some more things, you need to open new cmd window. The same is for the karma. If I run `karma start` command, then I need to open new cmd window for `karma run`

So the question is how to unblock cmd window to be able to executes new comands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just start your apps with the `start` command:

```
start /b node server.js
```

Comment: If they emit to the console, the output could be a mess with the `/b` option.

Comment: The only way to maintain your existing console is to run the job in the background.